# How to Configure PDF Initial View Settings in DITA Output

Tags: pdf, view

When the PDF output is generated using DITA OT, I want the Initial View settings to be set dynamically with the following values:

- **Navigation** = Bookmarks Panel and Page
- **Page layout** = Single Page Continuous
- **Magnification** = Fit Page
- **Open to Page** = 1

**Window Options**

- **Resize window to initial view**
- **Show** = Document Title

### Rendering Engines

- Apache FOP
- Oxygen PDF Chemistry

Could someone please help me figure out which files to modify or add to the DITA OT plugins to get this done?

Comment: You should specify your rendering engine. I do not think those settings are the same for each one.

Comment: The rendering engines are Oxygen PDF Chemistry or Apache FOP